# Alternative to mb_convert_encoding with HTML-ENTITIES charset

Tags: php, string, character-encoding

I have the following code:

```
mb_convert_encoding($string, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'utf-8');
```

I need to have an alternative code which does exactly the same but does not use any mb_* functions (the mb extension is not available on some environments).

I thought that

```
utf8_decode(htmlentities($string, ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'));
```

should do exactly the same, but unfortunately it does not.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I played around a bit, and find this very interesting. It seems like the second part also runs "htmlspecialchars". Must be some bug in mb_convert_encoding, as htmlentities is not run correctly.

If you run htmlspecialchars_decode over the result, you get exactly the same as if you would use mb_convert_encoding.

The code:

```
$string = 'Test:!"$%&/()=ÖÄÜöäü<<';
echo mb_convert_encoding($string, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'utf-8')."\n\n";
echo htmlspecialchars_decode(utf8_decode(htmlentities($string, ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8', false)));
```

Here a demo of the code above:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/715acade3b8337d9c9e48e58deee2a237015c259

And here a demo without htmlspecialchars_decode, to show your problem:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5c4a32bf99aa8fd6246c4a77132a023d32945363

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day! This works well with DOMDocument :)

Comment: What if we want convert from HTML-ENTITIES to utf-8 ? mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');

Comment: try this solution.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58182412/webviews-loaddata-is-not-working-in-android-10-0-q/58182876#58182876

Comment: `utf8_decode()` is deprecated too

Comment: @VincentDaveTe the link you've shared is for an Android WebView :-S

Comment: @acesta, `mb_convert_encoding()` in your updated solution is deprecated as well - and was the function to be omitted as per the original question.

Answer (score 2):

The solution "htmlspecialchars_decode(utf8_decode(htmlentities($string, ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8', false)));" don't have the good result, here another solution  :

```php
    $string = 'Test:!"$%&/()=ÖÄÜöäü<<accentué За матеріалами';
    echo mb_convert_encoding($string, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'utf-8')."\n\n";
    echo mb_encode_numericentity(
        htmlspecialchars_decode(
            htmlentities($string, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8', false)
            ,ENT_NOQUOTES
        ), [0x80, 0x10FFFF, 0, ~0],
        'UTF-8'
    );
```

Here a demo :
https://onlinephp.io/c/0a300

Comment: Could you share an example, which does not work with the accepted answer, but does work with your answer?

Comment: There is already valid answer in this question, topic started asked not to use any mb_ strings functions, but in your answer you're using it.

Comment: They are using `mb_encode_numericentity`. `mb_convert_encoding` is only in the example to demonstrate that it behaves similarily.

Comment: Note that this will turn `&gt;` back to `>` and `&lt;` back to `<`, which is not what happens when using `mb_convert_encoding`.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the same results as @Green Black, but with a simpler syntax:

```php
htmlspecialchars_decode(htmlentities($string))
```

Expanding on @Green Black's example:

```php
$string = 'Test:!"$%&/()=ÖÄÜöäü<<';
// Deprecated:
$test1 = mb_convert_encoding($string, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'utf-8');
// Version from @Green Black:
$test2 = htmlspecialchars_decode(utf8_decode(htmlentities($string, ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8', false)));
// Simplified version:
$test3 = htmlspecialchars_decode(htmlentities($string));

echo "\n\n$test1";
echo "\n\n$test2";
echo "\n\n$test3";

if ($test1 == $test2 && $test1 == $test3) {
    echo "\n\n✅ All versions match!";
};
```

Online Demo: https://onlinephp.io/c/ff03b

More Information at https://php.watch/versions/8.2/mbstring-qprint-base64-uuencode-html-entities-deprecated#html