# Alternative to mb_convert_encoding with mb_list_encodings() charset

Tags: php

```
$str = mb_convert_encoding((string) $str, 'UTF-8', mb_list_encodings());
```

Can you please help me to figure out a equivalent line of the above code.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Check this link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974008/alternative-to-mb-convert-encoding-with-html-entities-charset

Comment: I already check this. But the problem is  {mb_list_encodings()} this portion.
If I use this {mb_list_encodings()} the character set looks good. But my server php version can not compile that function. So I want something new for that function. 
Thanks.